# How to create a custom Ubuntu alternate CD?

Tags: ubuntu

I want to create a custom Ubuntu/Kubuntu alternate CD and install it on multiple computers.

I do not want a live CD. Some tutorials and apps are for live CD and does not work for alternate CD. There are apps that insert entire system to an iso image, including user's files, computer settings and hardware-dependent settings.

The following tutorial is difficult to understand and it is incomplete:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization

I need to:

- remove some useless packages
- add some useful packages
- remove other languages texts and packages
- add the rest of my local language packages that the system asks to install when it starts at first time
- add more repositories
- choose default settings of apps and desktop
- run a bash script after everything be installed

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The guide you linked seems complete to me and I doubt anyone here is going to take the time to re-write it for you :\ but....

If the computers are all identical in hardware you could install/customize the system and then clone it using something like [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) after that you could just clone the image to the other computers using clonezilla again.